# Best way to notify UIInterfaceOrientation changes to other viewControllers

Tags: ios, notifications, uiinterfaceorientation

I am looking for the best way to notify all the `viewControllers` of `UIInterfaceOrientation` changing that is detected in first-viewController added to mainWindow.

Do I have to `NSNotification` in the controller where these events are detected and other controllers will subscribe to that? Or there is any cleaner way?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Posting an `NSNotification` seems fine to me.

Comment: I read somewhere on stackoverflow that UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification is issued when orientation changes . So I will try that..

Answer (score 2):

Add `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` in viewDidLoad which anyView you wanted to notify  would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your UIViewController already get rotation notification messages:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

and

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

and also

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: willRotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated.